# python subprocess and unicode execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python, unicode, subprocess

I have a django site where I need to call a script using subprocess. The subprocess call works when I'm using ascii characters but when I try to issue arguments that are utf-8 encoded, I get an error:

```
execv() arg 2 must contain only strings.
```

The string `u'Wiadomo\u015b\u0107'` is coming from a postgres db. This example is using polish words. When I run it using english words, I have no issues.

The call looks like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/lib/p3web2/src/post_n_campaigns.py', '-c', u'bm01', '-1', u'Twoja', '-2', u'Wiadomo\u015b\u0107', '-3', u'', '-4', u'', '-5', u'', '-6', u'', '-m', u'pl', '-p', 'yes'])
```

I'm not sure how to handle the strings in this case. The odd thing is that this works fine when i run it through the python interpreter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should encode the Unicode strings in the encoding your program expects. If you know the program expects UTF-8:

```
u'Wiadomo\u015b\u0107'.encode('utf8')
```

If you don't know what encoding you need, you could try your platform's default encoding:

```
u'Wiadomo\u015b\u0107'.encode()
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick...I thought it was already encoded...lesson learned.